# removing the value that didn't exist in key with scala (PageRank)

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, pagerank

I'm trying to build a pagerank algorithm by scala.

I have a data set download form here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

It's a wikipedia database.

I've already map the title and the links appears in the title page like below

```
graph = 
TitleA, LinkB LinkC LinkD
TitleB, linkC
TitleD, linkA
```

A,B,C means that they have the same name but exist in title area or link area.

Now, I need to remove the Link that didn't exist in title.

So, the output should be

```
corgraph = 
TitleA, LinkB LinkD
TitleB, linkC
TitleD, linkA
```

by removing LinkC from titleA.

Here is my code for reference

```
val graph = lines.flatMap (line => {
        val titlePattern = "<title>(.+?)</title>".r //define regex of title string out from <title> tag
        val linkPattern = "\\[\\[(.+?)([\\|#]|\\]\\])".r  //define regex of link string out from [[]] area          
        val title = titlePattern.findFirstMatchIn(line).get.group(1) // find title by defined regex

        //find all link in pages and do map reduce
        linkPattern.findAllIn(line).matchData.map(link => {
          val corlink = link.group(1).replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&gt;", ">").replaceAll("&amp;", "&").replaceAll("&quot;", "\"").replaceAll("&apos;", "\'")
          val cortitle = title.replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&gt;", ">").replaceAll("&amp;", "&").replaceAll("&quot;", "\"").replaceAll("&apos;", "\'")
          (cortitle -> corlink)
        })               
    }).map{ case(url, link) => if(graph.contains(link))(url -> link)}
```

And the error message

```
[error] PageRank.scala:28:recursive value graph needs type
[error] }).map{ case(url, link) => 
if(graph.contains(link))(url -> link)}(url -> link)}
```

anyone can help? thanks.